# Browsersync on remote Server

Tags: node.js, gulp, typo3, browser-sync

i'm running browsersync through gulp in a typo3 instance.
my setup provides a local html based project and a remote running server with a typo3 instance.
local snyc works like a charm, but i want to have the livereload on my typo3 instance to while working. Unfortunately the servers i'm working on do not provide any nodejs support. so i have to manage anything locally. 
changed files will get pushed to the remote ftp server.

to my logic it should just work if i run my project locally (html version) and embed the sync snippet to my remote server html output.

```
<script type='text/javascript' id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.2.8.0.js'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script>
```

it creates multiple request, but not the required websocket.

**Do i need to provide any extra configuration?**

```
// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init([], {
        server: {
            baseDir: "./template",
        }
    });
    gulp.watch("template/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

[image]

Comment: to bypass those problems i created a gulp setup that fits my needs. maybe anyone is interested: https://github.com/CanKattw/yo-typo3-gulp

it is a  basic typo3 setup with gulp, livereload, less, js, ...